# MAAS 2.1 commissioning failure in cloudinit

Tags: maas

I'm running MAAS 2.1. Every server I try to commission fails with these two errors (on the GUI )
Node commissioning failure - 'cloudinit' running modules for config
Node commissioning failure - 'cloudinit' running config-ntp with frequency once-per-instance

Can anyone shed some light onto the reason?

The only thing I see in the node's message log that looks strange are these lines:

```
cloud-init[1985]: request to http://10.20.0.2:5240/MAAS/metadata//2012-03-01/maas-commissioning-scripts failed. sleeping 32.: HTTP Error 401: OK

cloud-init[1985]: Traceback (most recent call last):

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/tmp/user_data.sh.FluMuf/bin/maas-get", line 47, in <module>

cloud-init[1985]:     main()

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/tmp/user_data.sh.FluMuf/bin/maas-get", line 44, in main

cloud-init[1985]:     sys.stdout.buffer.write(geturl(url, creds))

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/tmp/user_data.sh.FluMuf/bin/maas_api_helper.py", line 110, in geturl

cloud-init[1985]:     raise error

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/tmp/user_data.sh.FluMuf/bin/maas_api_helper.py", line 90, in geturl

cloud-init[1985]:     return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen

cloud-init[1985]:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open

cloud-init[1985]:     response = meth(req, response)

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response

cloud-init[1985]:     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error

cloud-init[1985]:     return self._call_chain(*args)

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain

cloud-init[1985]:     result = func(*args)

cloud-init[1985]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default

cloud-init[1985]:     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

cloud-init[1985]: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: OK

cloud-init[1985]: tar: This does not look like a tar archive

cloud-init[1985]: tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: I see the same error. Upgraded a working MAAS 2.0 installation to 2.1 and now 2.2.